# Modify my Function for Datatable to CSV

Tags: c#

I wrote a function to Save datatable to CSV file format. But problem is that function remove old data and write new data when i call the function. I just want to keep my old data and write new data end of the file. How can I do that? My function is:

```
        public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dt, string strFilePath, bool isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (isFirstRowHeader == true)
        {
            var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }

        File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.AppendAllText` instead of `File.WriteAllText` will append to the end of your existing CSV file.  You'll need to avoid writing out the headers if the file exists already, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a StreamWriter instead and set its append parameter to true.

```
        string filename = @"c:\test.csv";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("test1");
        sb.Append("test2");

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true);
        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();
```

This should do the trick.